# php exec delete files from rar

Tags: php

I'm trying to remove a file from a rar archive.
if you run `/usr/bin/rar d rar_file.rar del.txt` this command deletes the file del.txt from rar_file.rar

I'm tring to run this in php using exec(), but it's not working.

```
<?php
$file = realpath("temp/temp.rar");
chmod($file, 0777); //make sure I can handle the file
if(file_exists($file)){ //Make sure that the file exists
    $rar = escapeshellarg($file);
    echo "/usr/bin/rar d $rar teste.txt"; //Lets see the command
    exec("/usr/bin/rar d $rar teste.txt", $r);
}
echo "\n";
print_r($r);
?>
```

Here's my output:

```
/usr/bin/rar d '/var/www/temp/temp.rar' teste.txt
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => RAR 3.90 beta 2   Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Alexander Roshal   3 Jun 2009
    [2] => Shareware version         Type RAR -? for help
)
```

Didn't delete the teste.txt file from the rar.

But, I copied the command `/usr/bin/rar d '/var/www/temp/temp.rar' teste.txt` and executed in terminal.
Here's my output:

```
stive@stive-laptop:~$ /usr/bin/rar d '/var/www//temp/temp.rar' teste.txt

RAR 3.90 beta 2   Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Alexander Roshal   3 Jun 2009
Shareware version         Type RAR -? for help

Deleting from /var/www/temp/temp.rar
Deleting teste.txt
Done
```

Works perfectly, but in php exec didn't.
I don't think it's file permissions cause the user www-data created the rar file (I created before) and I set the permissions to 777 without problems.

I'm using linux, sure.

What I'm doing wrong?
thanks!

Comment: I didn't like what I've did, but worked. I added a cron job to rrun in the next minute and the cronjob deleted the file from the rar. the cronjob can be easily added by running exec("crontab file.txt"). Maybe I use this as a solution, but I still want know why exec didnt work

Comment: Look into the `error.log` for messages, or add `2>&1` behind the exec command to get error output displayed as well.

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution. Adding 2>&1 shows me a permission denied to create a temp rar file. So I just chmoded the www path (where the script was running from), and know works!

Comment: Please post your solution as answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

When you execute something using exec(), for some reason the exec() stops before the script finish... This appends with many scripts that I've did.

So, the solution, by mario, helps me, adding a `2>&1` in the command, exec() only stop when the script finishes.